# Should I expose a protected std::vector?

Tags: c++

I have a class which I intend for others to inherit from. It has a std::vector which I only want developers to be able to read from, but not modify, my base functions modify it. Should I provide a function that returns a const iterator, or expose the vector as protected.

Thanks

Comment: Rule of thumb: don't expose data members, not even `protected`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you expose the vector as protected, subclasses will be able to modify it. So, you should expose methods that return const iterators.

You can use the [Non-Virtual Interface idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) to expose different interfaces for users and subclasses.

Answer (score 4):

If you protected it, then you lose your protection because any subclass can change it to public and let others to modify it.

Why not provide a const reference? If return const iterator, you may need to rewrite a lot interfaces including begin, end, size etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the derived class to modify the vector, then I think the answer is straight forward : provide function to return read-only iterator!

Returning iterator also encapsulates the base class which obviously is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Cons for making it protected:  can't easily change to different container, loss of control over allowed operations, coding to implementation instead of interface, harder to contain testing

Cons for function returning iterator:  a little extra typing (probably less than it took to ask this question)

Seems like an obvious answer to me.